# After web hoster change should I change dns A record on old dns server or pont new host to old dns

Tags: dns, hosting

I changed hosting company which hosted my page to a other one but domain is still hosted by the old company. I can do two things:
- I can change "A" record in the old company control panel to point to new IP.
- I can input old company dns servers to control panel of new one
maybe I should figure out new company dns servers and input them in old company as external dns?
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options are acceptable. The second option is more easy for you, because you should also enter CNAME and MX records if you choose the first one.